# Div height fix for % based columns

Tags: css, html, height, fluid, col

I have a webpage i've started at following address: http://digitalgenesis.com.au/my%20sites/Digital%20Genesis/

Basically im after a 2 column layout with 2 fluid containers that display background colour down to footer evenly.

At the moment however the left column will only display a background around the ammount of text. The code for the 2 columns and its containing div are listed below

```
#container{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}

#col1{
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
 background:red;
}

#col2{
 float: left;
 width:40%;
 background:blue;
}
```

I'm stumped as to how i can get the left column displaying a red background full length of page

Should i just resort to a fixed width sidebar to make it easier?

Comment: see http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks
its a common problem.

Comment: you don't have to, but personally I always limit the with of my websites as a hole, centering all the content (in large displays, it doesn't stretch to the "infinite", mantaining everything in order)

Answer (score 0):

[see this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/qLNTt/).  That approach works by treating the backgrounds separately from the content.  It introduces an absolute-positioned background div for each column.  The backgrounds are positioned behind the floated content using percentages, and sized to fill the height of the parent container.

**note:** even though my example is hosted at jsFiddle, this method does not involve any javascript.  It uses *CSS only*.

Answer (score 0):

[**Faux Columns**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is a technique worth looking at.

But personally I chose to use javascript because it's just SO easy.

```
$.fn.equalHeights = function(px) {
    $(this).each(function(){ 
            var currentTallest = 0;
            $(this).children().each(function(i){
                    if ($(this).height() > currentTallest) { currentTallest = $(this).height(); }
            });
            if (!px || !Number.prototype.pxToEm) currentTallest = currentTallest.pxToEm(); //use ems unless px is specified
            // for ie6, set height since min-height isn't supported
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6.0) { $(this).children().css({'height': currentTallest}); }
            $(this).children().css({'min-height': currentTallest}); 
    });
    return this;
};
```

$('.equal-height').equalHeights();

95% compatibility for equal heights is good enough for me MOST of the time.  If not, i use faux columns.  Although I believe this problem should go away entirely with HTML5/CSS3 when the browsers catch up.